# How to get info of radio button of command "L.control.layers"?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use this code :

```
L.control.layers(WMS, null, {collapsed: true}).addTo(mymap); 
//WMS = group of wms layer
```

to add radio button in leaflet and I would like to know which button was selected to be able to execute overs JS functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery I check if there is a click on the button like this :

```
$(".leaflet-control-layers-selector").on('click',function(){.....});
```

In the function I use the function `map.eachLayer(....);` to execute different program on each layers.

Note : `".leaflet-control-layers-selector"` is the class generate by leaflet for the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map.hasLayer(myLayer)` to test if a layer is added to the map.

Comment: Thanks you I will try.